# How does one use a CDSView with MultiLine on GMAPPlot?

Tags: bokeh, renderer

(First Question so apologies)

Bokeh 1.3.4

Situation:

I am trying top map a Bokeh MultiLine using a CDSView and all the existing examples seem to use the "figure" object which has a helper (multi_line) which accepts a view as an argument. I am doing this on top of a GMAPPlot which does not support multi_line (only MultiLine) (see below). The commented out line throws an error saying GMAPPlot does not support multi_line.

```
plot = GMapPlot(
        x_range=Range1d(), y_range=Range1d(), map_options=map_options, sizing_mode='scale_height'
    )
.
.
.
sel_sa1s = []
v_bf = [True if sa1_val in sel_sa1s else False for sa1_val in v_source.data['SA1']]
v_view = CDSView(source=v_source, filters=[BooleanFilter(v_bf)])
v_ml = MultiLine(xs="xs",ys="ys",line_color="black", line_width="w")

#v_rend = plot.multi_line(xs="xs",ys="ys",line_color="black", line_width="w", source=v_source, view=v_view)

v_rend = plot.add_glyph(v_source, v_ml, name='votes')
```

The snippet shown above works and maps the entire network (very crowded) because there is no filter. What I want to have happen is for the filter to be initialised to hide everything then when the user clicks on an area (SA1) it will display the network related to that SA1.

Actually I can do that but only one area at a time and it would be much more efficient to be able to load the whole map and use a filtered view to control which sub-networks are displayed.

It seems that GMAPPlot only likes the pattern:

- create glyph
- add glyph

So, my question is - how does one use a CDSView in this environment (how does one add it to the renderer?)

[Screenshot of unfiltered data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggE5R.png)

Answer (score 0):

> It seems that GMAPPlot only likes the pattern:
>
> ```
> create glyph
> add glyph
> ```

That has not been true for some time. There is a higher level [`bokeh.plotting.gmap`](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/geo.html#google-maps) function that creates and configures `GMapPlot` instances with deafult axes, etc, and also has all the same methods and conveniences as `figure` (e.g. `multi_line`). It will be much less work to go this route than assembling everything by hand from low-level objects.

Comment: Many thanks - I did look but clearly not hard enough